# creating a jquery ui dialog

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm wondering everything I need to do have just a basic jquery dialog appear on the screen. Here is my code below. Any help why none of the UI properties are being rendered when executing the code below? All that happens currently if a user clicks on the button, a dialog modal should be appared but it is not displayed why ?
here the html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>modal box</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
    <style>
        body { font-size: 62.5%; };
        label, input { display:block; };
        input.text { margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em; };
        fieldset { padding:0; border:0; margin-top:25px; };
        .ui-dialog .ui-state-error { padding: .3em; }
        .validateTips { border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 0.3em; }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function() {
    var dialog;
            dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 300,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Create an account": addUser,
                Cancel: function() {
                    dialog.dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            close: function() {
                form[ 0 ].reset();
                allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
            }
        });
        });

    </script>
</head>
    <body>
      <div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
        <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>
        <form>
          <fieldset>
              <label for="name">Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Jane Smith" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
              <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="jane@smith.com" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
              <label for="password">Password</label>
              <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="xxxxxxx" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">

              <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
              <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <button id="create-user">Create new user</button>
 </div>     
 </body>
```

style.css

```
   body {
      font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Helvetica", "Arial",  "Verdana", "sans-serif";
      font-size: 62.5%;
   }
```

jquery-ui.css

```
 .ui-widget {
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
 }
 .ui-widget .ui-widget {
    font-size: 1em;
 }
 .ui-widget input,
 .ui-widget select,
 .ui-widget textarea,
 .ui-widget button {
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
 }
 .ui-widget-content {
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    background: #ffffff url("images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
    color: #222222;
 }
 .ui-widget-content a {
    color: #222222;
 }
 .ui-widget-header {
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    background: #cccccc url("images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
    color: #222222;
    font-weight: bold;
 }
 .ui-widget-header a {
    color: #222222;
 }
```

Comment: I'm assuming the "Create New User" button is the one that is supposed to open the dialog? Currently you have no `.click()` handlers wired up to open the dialog and you have `autoOpen: false`. How are you expecting the dialog to appear?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but where is the `click event handler` for the `button` that will actually show the `dialog`?

Comment: It looks like you're just creating the `dialog` but there's nothing to actually display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to add the `.click()` handler to open the dialog. Currently, there is no click handler and you have `autoOpen: false`. The dialog will be created but it just won't be opened.

Assuming "Create New User" is the button to press to open the dialog, try adding the following in your document ready function:

```
$('#create-user').on('click', function () {
    dialog.dialog("open");
});
```

**Full Document Ready Snippet:**

```
/* Initialize the dialog */
$(function() {
    var dialog;
    dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Create an account": addUser,
            Cancel: function() {
                dialog.dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            form[ 0 ].reset();
            allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
        }
    });

    /* Create a handler to open the dialog */
    $('#create-user').on('click', function () {
        dialog.dialog("open");
    });
});
```

In addition, I don't believe objects can have spaces in their property names. Your property *"Create an account"* in the button object is invalid. Try renaming it to *"createAnAccount"*.

**API Reference:** [`.dialog("open");`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-open)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call `dialog("open");`.

Your `autoOpen` parameter is set to `false`. it disables opening the dialog automatically.

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/H7Ybx/)**

You need to comment out a code line `"Create an account": addUser,` because `function addUser` in not defined, and then after you will need to add code line `dialog.dialog("open");` after your dialog initialization is completed to open the dialog.

complete JS code:

```
$(function() {
    var dialog;
            dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 300,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                //"Create an account": addUser,
                Cancel: function() {
                    dialog.dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            close: function() {
                form[ 0 ].reset();
                allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
            }
        });
    dialog.dialog("open");
 });
```